# pouchdb putAttachment function throws error in IE10

Tags: pouchdb

In Internet Explorer browser(IE 10) db.putAttachment() function is throwing the following error when I attempt to store a base64 encoded data.

```
db.putAttachment( id, attachmentTitle, attachmentBase64EncodedData, attachmentType); 

message "Some query argument is invalid"
name    "badarg"
reason  "Attachments need to be base64 encoded"
status  500
```

The base64 encoded data that  am trying to store as attachment is retrieved from server.

The same code works perfectly in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that IE10 does not support Base64 option for PouchDB, so try using Blob instead.

[PouchDB and attachment strategies](http://pouchdb.com/faq.html#data_limits)

Answer (score 0):

When you supply attachments to PouchDB, you need to either provide them as 1) base64-encoded strings, or 2) Blobs. Your error indicates that you passed in a string, but it isn't base64-encoded.

I encourage you to try the live code examples in [the PouchDB guide to attachments](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html). They definitely work in IE10. :)

Also FWIW it is more efficient if you pass in Blobs to PouchDB rather than base64-encoded strings (if you can avoid it!).